# Using Iterative Projection to solve KL divergence Problem.

Tags: matrices

My problem is  to find an optimal or near-optimal matrix,

$ min_{\Gamma} KL(\mathbf \Gamma || \mathbf \Gamma_1)$  with a value $\Gamma_1$ , under conditions

(1) $\Gamma \mathbf{1} = \mathbf1$

(2) $\Gamma^ \mathrm{ T }  \mathbf1= \mathbf1$

(3) $ \mathbf C \Gamma=  \mathbf 1 \mathbf 1^ \mathrm{ T }  $.

How Can I solve it using matlab.  I find some one use Iterative Bregman Projections to solve a similar problem without the condition (3).

Can some one help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: what are $C$ and $1$ for you?

Comment: $C$ is a matrix and $\mathbf{1}$ is a column vector with all items are 1.

Comment: @Exodd  $C$ is a matrix and $\mathbf{1}$ is a column vector with all items are 1.

Comment: @littleO Dear littleO, sorry to disturb you. I saw you solved another similar problem using proximal method. Is this also suitable for proximal method, and how to calculate the proximal for the indicator function used to enforce the constraint that all these matrix should be equal.

Comment: @martini Dear martini. I saw you answered a similar problem, could you help me solve this via proximal method?